# Need some advise on pitching Ubuntu SBS and desktops for my company

Tags: community, ubuntu-advantage

In the next couple of weeks I need to present an IT presentation for future I equipment for the small company I would with.  The have been shrouded by the Microsoft and Apple blanket and introducing Ubuntu to them is going to be a tough task.

Can anyone give me some advise who has had the task of pitching Ubuntu for business being the favourable OS over Windows which they are currently using?  I will say none of them are tech-savvy and some of them don't even know how to send emails.

Any advice would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: **To the person who I *know* is going to say this isn't a question, it is, and a perfectly legitimate question.** Ok, enough with the bold. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No viruses
2. Updates arrive faster, and cause less problem to the system.
3. Free software from software center.
4. More stable
5. Less memory footprint ( Older machines also supported)
6. Less installed size (Win7 requires 16 GB without Office!)
7. Working Out of the Box (no need to mess with drivers)
8. Fix release schedules, upgrades can be planned.
9. Updates don't require always restart.
10. Ask Ubuntu, if they need any help.

Comment: 1.Ok/2.really? haven't we here had our fair share of users asking for help when updating?/3.ok/4.Mostly yes/5.Indeed, correct./6.I don't think a User would switch to a different OS just because it uses less space/7.On a Generic PC yes, but if it has some special hardware they will have a problem/8.Yes/9.OK../10.Correct.

Comment: 2. On Windows, you have monthly updates, which come on the second Tuesday every month. If you don't have a proxy, this might use to much network. Also I had to repair more unbootable XP-s than Ubuntu. 7. Special hardware also causes problems on windows.

Comment: I mean that Updating caused many users a headache because X update to X component of the system broke said system. While i never experienced that In Ubuntu or Windows i can't vouch for it not happening to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Identify what the needs of the business in question - Office applications ? mail server ? file or print server ? web server ? etc.

Identify the hardware and check compatibility. If you plan to purchase hardware, check compatibility before you purchase.

Do not over sell Ubuntu. Identify it's strengths and weaknesses.

Identify how you are going to support Ubuntu.

Identify possible alternates to Ubuntu from RHEL to Novell to BSD.

Choose the OS that best meets the needs of your business.